# Get most-occurring NSString in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsstring

Given an array of `NSString`s which have several repeated copies:

```
AAA
BBB
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
BBB
CCC
```

What's the easiest way to get the string which is most occurring?

Comment: You want fast or simple?

Comment: (Sort the array, keep a pointer to the most popular string and it's count.  Walk through the array, noting when strings change.  Count identical strings, and if the new count is > "most popular" update the "most popular" pointer and its count.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then find the largest `countForObject:`.

```
NSCountedSet *bag = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:myArray];

NSString *mostOccurring;
NSUInteger highest = 0;
for (NSString *s in bag)
{
    if ([bag countForObject:s] > highest)
    {
        highest = [bag countForObject:s];
        mostOccurring = s;
    }
}
```

Checking the result:

```
NSLog(@"Most frequent string: %@", mostOccurring);
```

Comment: Yep. This would be the better answer I was looking for.
 +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks. Am I wrong or your code is wrong ? you need to update highest variable as well.. ?