# Finding most repeated object in array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have an array full of strings with each string being a name. Some names may be the same while some may be different. The language I'm working in is objective-C. I want to be able to find out which name is most popular from this array (the array will be dynamic based on information given to the app from the user). I am not sure how to make this happen EFFICIENTLY. If someone could expand on this or provide an example, it would be appreciated.

Thank you

Example:

```
NSArray *nameArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects @"james", @"megan", @"lauren", @"mike" @james", nil]; 

  //james would be the most popular name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `NSCountedSet` and then find the object with highest count using  `countForObject:` method.

```
//create count set from array
NSCountedSet *setOfObjects = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:yourArrayhere];

//Declaration of objects
NSString *mostOccurringObject = @"";
NSUInteger highestCount = 0;

//Iterate in set to find highest count for a object
for (NSString *strObject in setOfObjects)
{
    NSUInteger tempCount = [setOfObjects countForObject:strObject];
    if (tempCount > highest)
    {
        highestCount = tempCount;
        mostOccurringObject = strObject;
    }
}
```

Checking the result:

```
NSLog(@"Most frequent string: %@ with count: %i", mostOccurringObject,highestCount);
```

**Credit** goes to [@Evan Mulawski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141256/1106035]) answer

Comment: Doesn't look very efficient (as the op asked): I bet each `[bag countForObject:]` goes through the whole array, and since you do it for each element of the array it's a O(n^2). The approach suggested by @Samir looks better.

Comment: it also same as each string in array is checked in whole array

Comment: @Saphrosit - While the behaviour of algorithms is not often given by Apple, for `NSCountedSet` its description states "Each distinct object inserted into an NSCountedSet object has a counter associated with it. NSCountedSet keeps track of the number of times objects are inserted [...] Thus, there is only one instance of an object in an NSSet object even if the object has been added to the set multiple times." So @Samir's and @Prince's are really the same underlying algorithm (hash table of counters) and the same order. `NSCountedSet` probably has the absolute perf edge, and is simpler to code.

Comment: @Prince About to put to this to the test, will let you all know in a couple of minutes. Thanks for the quick feedback

Comment: @CRD Well, even if the underlying structure is the same, it doesn't mean the efficiency in retrieving the result is the same...As you said, the algorithm used by Apple is not known in general, but I think  that every time you call `countForObject` the algorithm goes through the set looking for the object you asked (NSCountedSet is not ordered). Doing this for each object is a O(n^2). I may be wrong, but a better approach would be to enumerate the keys of a NSDictionary and, for each key, retrieve the value - O(n). Of course,not knowing the implementation of methods things may go differently...

Comment: @Saphrosit - Read my comment again, Apple **do** state how `NSCountedSet` works. Each object is store *once* along with an associated count, there is no search involved in `countForObject:` - it is a hash lookup just as `NSDictionary` performs. HTH.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a hash table (`NSMutableDictionary` in your case), go through the array of strings, use each string as key, and set its value as the number its occurrences in the array. You can keep track of the maximum using a variable (or an array of names if there is multiple names with the same number of occurrences).

The running time is then linear ( O(n) where n is the number of names in your array ).

Comment: Prince provided an example so that is why I gave him the checkmark. I have up'd your answer because it is also correct and Thank you for providing it!

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of occurrences.

```
NSArray *nameArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects @"james", @"megan", @"lauren", @"mike" @james", nil]; 
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] nameArray];
```